# an adsense bid reset button for people who just improved their site

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies, advertising

I don't like it sometimes when google adsense does things automatically because they are too slow.

Since I updated my website a bit, I want to be able to access a google URL once to indicate to them that my website has been updated and that the advertisers should re-think or redo their bids so that I get more accurate income.

I know one way is to go through each custom channel and change some info about each one even by one character, but I don't always want to take that route.

Is there another way I can do this?

I ask because I notice that when google believes I follow adsense rules 100% I consistently make more than 10 cents a day every day, but when they believe I screw up, I'll be lucky if I make 8 cents a day.

The problem is there is no way of me knowing the minute I have screwed up since I never get emails from them.and I only notice google's decisions through income at least several hours later. I'd rather know their decisions right away so I can fix any problems necessary right away and make the world happy.

I figure if I find that hidden "bid reset" button, then I can use it to tell advertisers to reset their bids for all ads on my site so I can get better income because then I'm telling everyone that I improved my site and want all to see. I don't want to wait around for several hours until google is ready to check my site. The hours are killing me.

Is there any way I can get access to this "bid reset" button that I described other than the method I described above?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do this at the moment. Google won't let you force a recheck of your site out of their standard check for adsense.

Comment: Your answer sounds right, but what are you basing it on?   Is this from your personal experience with AdSense, or is that documentation about how the bids work that could be relevant?

Comment: I'm basing this on a question I asked Google about a year ago which was very similar and also to do with rechecking AdSense sites.